# Multiple databases in Strapi

Tags: strapi

Is it possible to use two different databases, i.e MongoDB and Redis, simultaneously in Strapi?
I want to keep track of my refresh tokens by Redis, while all other documents on Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, buit Strapi does not support Redis

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default', // this defines the default connections
  connections: {
    default: { //that's the default connection
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'sqlite',
        filename: env('DATABASE_FILENAME', '.tmp/main.db'), //uses main db
      },
      options: {
        useNullAsDefault: true,
      },
    },
    messages: { //that's the connection for messages db
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'sqlite',
        filename: env('DATABASE_FILENAME', '.tmp/messages.db'), //uses another db
      },
      options: {
        useNullAsDefault: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```